# What is a good way to implement several very similar functions?

Tags: python, oop

I need several very similar plotting functions in python that share many arguments, but differ in some and of course also differ slightly in what they do. This is what I came up with so far:

- Obviously just defining them one after the other and copying the code they share is a possibility, though not a very good one, I reckon.
- One could also transfer the "shared" part of the code to helper functions and call these from inside the different plotting functions. This would make it tedious though, to later add features that all functions should have.
- And finally I've also thought of implementing one "big" function, making possibly not needed arguments optional and then deciding on what to do in the function body based on additional arguments. This, I believe, would make it difficult though, to find out what really happens in a specific case as one would face a forest of arguments.

I can rule out the first option, but I'm hard pressed to decide between the second and third. So I started wondering: is there another, maybe object-oriented, way? And if not, how does one decide between option two and three?

I hope this question is not too general and I guess it is not really python-specific, but since I am rather new to programming (I've never done OOP) and first thought about this now, I guess I will add the python tag.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by many, this question is quite general and it was intended to be so, but I understand that this makes answering it rather difficult. So here's some info on the problem that caused me to ask:

I need to plot simulation data, so all the plotting problems have simulation parameters in common (location of files, physical parameters,...). I also want the figure design to be the same. But depending on the quantity, some plots will be 1D, some 2D, some should contain more than one figure, sometimes I need to normalize the data or take a logarithm before plotting it. The output format might also vary.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: It really depends on how the functions are similar.  I don't really understand why you think option 2 would make it tedious to add shared features; it seems like it would make it less tedious than option 1.  Can you give an example of some set of functions illustrating what you're asking about?

Comment: The question is way too general. Show code for the task you have problem with.

Comment: Well it would make it necessary to add a line calling a helper function in every declaration as opposed to option three, where you'd only have to add one line. But you're right, it's certainly less tedious than in option one.

Comment: I do number 2 often by implementing a class with a method that implements the overall algorithm by calling other methods on the object. Child classes override methods to change actions.

Comment: What about option 3, 4 ,5 or 6? How about you tell us what the heck are you doing?

Comment: Well, it was intended to be quite general, maybe too general. I don't really have a specific problem in my code. I need to plot different quantities from simulation data. So the functions would have all the simulation parameters in common for example. But depending on the quantity I plot I have to treat it differently (take a logarithm e.g.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. You can create a Base class that will have a method `foo` that is your base shared method that performs all the similar code. Then for your different classes you can inherit from `Base` and super the method of interest and extend the implementation to whatever extra functionality you need.

Here is an example of how it works. Note the different example I provided between how to use super in Python 2 and Python 3.

```
class Base:            
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("foo stuff from Base")
        return "return something here"


class SomeClass(Base):
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # python 2
        #x = super(SomeClass, self).foo(*args, **kwargs)
        # python 3
        x = super().foo(*args, **kwargs)
        print(x)
        print("SomeClass extension of foo")

s = SomeClass()
s.foo()
```

Output:

```
foo stuff from Base
return something here
SomeClass extension of foo from Base
```

Comment: This might be the "object oriented method" I was looking for. I was thinking about creating classes of functions, but that is probably not the right notion of it as a class is not a function clearly. So doing it your way I could create a class "Plot" with a method that does all the shared stuff and child classes "xPlot" with an extension to that method? And I would have to instantiate every class once in order to be able to call those methods, so the classes themselves are only "containers" for the methods.

Answer (score 0):

More information needs to be given to fully understand the context. But, in a general sense, I'd do a mix of all of them. Use helper functions for "shared" parts, and use conditional statements too. Honestly, a lot of it comes down to just what is easier for you to do?